# Alternative in Serilog for NLog's "final" rule

Tags: c#, logging, nlog, serilog

It's possible to configure NLog like this:

```xml
<rules>
 <logger name="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="file-ef" final="true" />
 <logger name="Microsoft.*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="file-http,console" final="true" />
 <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="file,console" />
</rules>
```

The `final` keyword for [rules](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Configuration-file#rules) enables the possibility to use separate targets for:

1. `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.*` loggers
2. Other `Microsoft.*` loggers
3. All other loggers

The configuration is straightforward and logical, I can easily add another condition without modifying all other rules.

With Serilog to do the same thing I have to write the following code:

```cs
const string format = "[{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss.fff} {ThreadId} {Level:u3}] {Message:lj} [{SourceContext}] {NewLine}{Exception}";
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .MinimumLevel.Verbose()
            .Enrich.FromLogContext()
            .Enrich.WithThreadId()
            .WriteTo.Console(outputTemplate: format)
            .WriteTo.Logger(cfg => cfg
                .Filter.ByIncludingOnly(Matching.FromSource("Microsoft.AspNetCore"))
                .WriteTo.RollingFile(@"logs\{Date}.http.log", outputTemplate: format, retainedFileCountLimit: null, buffered: true))
            .WriteTo.Logger(cfg => cfg
                .Filter.ByIncludingOnly(Matching.FromSource("Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore"))
                .WriteTo.RollingFile(@"logs\{Date}.ef.log", outputTemplate: format, retainedFileCountLimit: null, buffered: true))
            .WriteTo.Logger(cfg => cfg.Filter
                .ByExcluding(Matching.FromSource("Microsoft"))
                .WriteTo.RollingFile(@"logs\{Date}.log", outputTemplate: format, retainedFileCountLimit: null, buffered: true))
            .CreateLogger();
```

To add another condition I would have to exclude it from all the other filters.

Question: am I missing something or there is no easy way to skip other rules if one is matched?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a scenario where Serilog's API is particularly strong,
 but [*Serilog.Sinks.Map*](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-map) covers this case.

```
    // Install-Package Serilog.Sinks.Map -Pre

    var isAsp = Matching.FromSource("Microsoft.AspNetCore");
    var isEF = Matching.FromSource("Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore");
    var isMS = Matching.FromSource("Microsoft");

    Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .WriteTo.Map(le => isAsp(le) ? ".http" :
                            isEF(le) ? ".ef" :
                            !isMS(le) ? ".other" :
                            "",
            (slug, wt) => wt.RollingFile($"logs\\{{Date}}{slug}.log"))
        .CreateLogger();
```

Comment: Yes, I've come across this project when searching or a solution, however defining rules where to write which kind of logs is still not that easy. And, I cannot specify multiple sinks per filter. Accepting the answer because the `final` case is covered indeed.

Comment: Thanks. The `(slug, wt) =>` delegate can be implemented in such a way as to configure different sinks based on the value of `slug`, if that helps.